# How to Use Multiple Datasets in a Single Tablix Region in SSRS for many to many relationship?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to use the below, but this is showing all blank values for the column "price" that is coming from dataset2

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!cust_id.Value, Fields!customer_id.Value, Fields!price.Value, "dataset2"), ", ")
```

Comment: why are you using a Join on a lookupset?

Comment: I have tried using without a join, it didn't work that way as well.

Comment: Lookupset specifies it is intended for 1 to many not many to many..

Comment: Can I know how to use for many to many ?

Comment: can you show your sample dataset and desired result?

Comment: I have posted the date set below

Comment: Harry, I have added the results, I just have to join these two data sets. Please let me know how to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

Harry here is the two data sets: I need to join on ID column in the SSRS. Can I know what expression I need to use ?? I have many to Many relationship

[This pic shows two datsets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYttV.png)

[the results should look something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc8Bn.png)

Comment: Do not answer your question with comments.. please edit your original question to add comments and content. what do you expect to see in your SSRS report output from the 2 datasets?